# Sorting HTML table column with JavaScript alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, php, html, sorting, columnsorting

I'm having an issue sorting my HTML table. The headers are clickable and they do sort, however it doesn't sort the table correctly. I'm using ACF Pro and FacetWP. The table is dynamic with PHP, need this to be able to sort alphanumerically. In theory this sort algorithm should work, but I'm not understanding why it's not sorting correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```js
cPrev = -1; // global var saves the previous c, used to
// determine if the same column is clicked again

function sortBy(c) {
  rows = document.getElementById("sortable").rows.length; // num of rows
  columns = document.getElementById("sortable").rows[0].cells.length; // num of columns
  arrTable = [...Array(rows)].map(e => Array(columns)); // create an empty 2d array

  for (ro = 0; ro < rows; ro++) { // cycle through rows
    for (co = 0; co < columns; co++) { // cycle through columns
      // assign the value in each row-column to a 2d array by row-column
      arrTable[ro][co] = document.getElementById("sortable").rows[ro].cells[co].innerHTML;
    }
  }

  th = arrTable.shift(); // remove the header row from the array, and save it

  if (c !== cPrev) { // different column is clicked, so sort by the new column
    arrTable.sort(
      function(a, b) {
        if (a[c] === b[c]) {
          return 0;
        } else {
          return (a[c] < b[c]) ? -1 : 1;
        }
      }
    );
  } else { // if the same column is clicked then reverse the array
    arrTable.reverse();
  }

  cPrev = c; // save in previous c

  arrTable.unshift(th); // put the header back in to the array

  // cycle through rows-columns placing values from the array back into the html table
  for (ro = 0; ro < rows; ro++) {
    for (co = 0; co < columns; co++) {
      document.getElementById("sortable").rows[ro].cells[co].innerHTML = arrTable[ro][co];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table id="sortable" style="width:100%;">
      <thead>
        <tr style="cursor:pointer">
          <th align="left">Address</th>
          <th onclick="sortBy(1)" align="left">City</th>
          <th onclick="sortBy(2)" align="left">State</th>
          <th onclick="sortBy(3)" align="left">Type</th>
          <th onclick="sortBy(4)" align="right">Available SF</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table-body">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
              <?php the_field('building_address'); ?>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td align="left">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
              <?php the_field('city'); ?>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td align="left">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
              <?php the_field('state'); ?>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td align="left">
            <?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'property_type', '', ', '); ?>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
              <?php the_field('max_available_size'); ?>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what does it mean it doesn't sort correctly? Try replacing `return (a[c] < b[c]) ? -1 : 1;` with `return (a[c]+'').localeCompare(b[c]);`

Comment: Why php, ACF Pro or FacetWP?
I've built an excellent and simple table sorter in pure JavaScript.

Comment: I'm working on a WordPress website

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use this function I will explain below the code of passed function parameter:
`colNo` is pass number of column data wise sort data.
`tableId` is same as your table id `sortable`.
`IsAsc` variable value is `true` then rows set ascending order otherwise row set descending order.
example of function calling `sortTable(1,"sortable",true)`.

```
function sortTable(colNo,tableId,IsAsc) {
          var table, rows, switching, i, x, y;
          table = document.getElementById(tableId);
          switching = true;
          while (switching) {
            switching = false;
            rows = table.rows;  
            for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
              if(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[colNo] != undefined && rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[colNo] != undefined)
              {
                x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[colNo].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[colNo].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                if ((x < y && IsAsc == false) || (x > y && IsAsc == true)) {
                  rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i+1], rows[i]);
                  switching = true;
                  break;
                }
              }
            }    
          }
        }
```

Also this function used for sort data date,time,numbers,alphabats wise.

---

I took the liberty to add a snippet with your solutions.

```js
function sortTable(colNo,tableId,IsAsc) {
          var table, rows, switching, i, x, y;
          table = document.getElementById(tableId);
          switching = true;
          while (switching) {
            switching = false;
            rows = table.rows;  
            for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
              if(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[colNo] != undefined && rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[colNo] != undefined)
              {
                x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[colNo].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[colNo].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                if ((x < y && IsAsc == false) || (x > y && IsAsc == true)) {
                  rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i+1], rows[i]);
                  switching = true;
                  break;
                }
              }
            }    
          }
        }
```

```html
  <table id="theTable" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <span>Header 1</span>
          <button onclick="sortTable(0,'theTable',true)">Asc</button>
          <button onclick="sortTable(0,'theTable',false)">Dsc</button>
        </th>
        <th>
          <span>Header 2</span>
          <button onclick="sortTable(1,'theTable',true)">Asc</button>
          <button onclick="sortTable(1,'theTable',false)">Dsc</button>
        </th>
        <th>
          <span>Header 3</span>
          <button onclick="sortTable(2,'theTable',true)">Asc</button>
          <button onclick="sortTable(2,'theTable',false)">Dsc</button>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Heavens</td>
        <td>and</td>
        <td>the</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>I</td>
        <td>created</td>
        <td>the</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>Took</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>nap</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>Earth</td>
        <td>Then</td>
        <td>I</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>At</td>
        <td>the</td>
        <td>begining</td>
      </tr>
      
      
      
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: IsAsc value `true` means row set in ascending order.`fales` means rows set in descending order.

Comment: Where is it stored?
Anyways, when using `true` it sorts rows in descending order, and vice versa.
Good job!

Comment: Perfect!
You can remove the code quote, the horizontal line, and my line = leave the snippet instead.